# Axis 2 and Rampart- why does service return wsse:Security header in request?

Tags: web-services, soap, https, apache-axis, rampart

I'm connecting to a secure service.

I have a SOAP UI project configured to use a jks file to provide the certificate, along with appropriate security settings to allow me to get a valid response.

I've have used AXIS 2 and Rampart to create a SOAP request from a JAVA project.
Using TCPMon I've managed to grab the SOAP request.

When the request runs in the JAVA project, I just get the response:

*org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request*

but if I take the same request, captured in TCPMon and put it in a SOAP UI project, I get a response successfully.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <soapenv:Header>  
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"  
soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">  
  <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"  
  wsu:Id="Timestamp-1">  
    <wsu:Created>2012-06-01T15:09:12.520Z</wsu:Created>  
    <wsu:Expires>2012-06-01T15:14:12.520Z</wsu:Expires>  
  </wsu:Timestamp>  
  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"  
  EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"  
  ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"  
  wsu:Id="CertId-ECDB0E....01">  
  MIID4DCCA0mgAwIBAgIBFjAN....</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>  
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"  
  Id="Signature-2">  
    <ds:SignedInfo>  
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />  
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />  
      <ds:Reference URI="#Id-15..93">  
        <ds:Transforms>  
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />  
        </ds:Transforms>  
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />  
        <ds:DigestValue>  
        3wgvhJ8SI2soC..IA=</ds:DigestValue>  
      </ds:Reference>  
      <ds:Reference URI="#Timestamp-1">  
        <ds:Transforms>  
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />  
        </ds:Transforms>  
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />  
        <ds:DigestValue>  
        VlzDT69YEl..qTlbj0=</ds:DigestValue>  
      </ds:Reference>  
    </ds:SignedInfo>  
    <ds:SignatureValue>  
    ZCRypw/..=</ds:SignatureValue>  
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-ECD..2">  
      <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"  
      wsu:Id="STRId-ECDB0E6..6193">  
        <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-ECDB0E..01"  
        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />  
      </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>  
    </ds:KeyInfo>  
  </ds:Signature>  
</wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-15..3"><ns2:ProductSearchV2Request xmlns:ns2="http://product.webservice.sxc.com">   
  <ns2:Strength>900</ns2:Strength>  
  <ns2:MaximumResultSetInd>true</ns2:MaximumResultSetInd>  
  <ns2:MaximumResultSet>100</ns2:MaximumResultSet>  
</ns2:ProductSearchV2Request>
```

This is the WS-POLICY document that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!--  
 !  
 ! Copyright 2006 The Apache Software Foundation.  
 !  
 ! Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");  
 ! you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  
 ! You may obtain a copy of the License at  
 !  
 !      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  
 !  
 ! Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software  
 ! distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  
 ! WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  
 ! See the License for the specific language governing permissions and  
 ! limitations under the License.  
 !-->  
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SigOnly"  
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"  
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">  
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>  
        <wsp:All>  
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">  
                <wsp:Policy>  
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>  
                        <wsp:Policy>  
                            <sp:X509Token  
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">  
                                <wsp:Policy>  
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>  
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>  
                                </wsp:Policy>  
                            </sp:X509Token>  
                        </wsp:Policy>  
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>  
                    <sp:RecipientToken>  
                        <wsp:Policy>  
                            <sp:X509Token  
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">  
                                <wsp:Policy>  
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>  
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>  
                                </wsp:Policy>  
                            </sp:X509Token>  
                        </wsp:Policy>  
                    </sp:RecipientToken>  
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>  
                        <wsp:Policy>  
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>  
                        </wsp:Policy>  
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>  
                    <sp:Layout>  
                        <wsp:Policy>  
                            <sp:Strict/>  
                        </wsp:Policy>  
                    </sp:Layout>  
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>  
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>  
                </wsp:Policy>  
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>  
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">  
                <wsp:Policy>  
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>  
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>  
                </wsp:Policy>  
            </sp:Wss10>  
            <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">  
                <sp:Body/>  
            </sp:SignedParts>  
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">  
                <ramp:user>ctr</ramp:user>  
                <ramp:encryptionUser>ctr</ramp:encryptionUser>  
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>com.gtnet.rampart.PWCBHandler  
                </ramp:passwordCallbackClass>  

                <ramp:signatureCrypto>  
                    <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">  
                        <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>  
                        <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">build\resources\qa.jks</ramp:property>  
                        <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">123123</ramp:property>  
                    </ramp:crypto>  
                </ramp:signatureCrypto>  
            </ramp:RampartConfig>  

        </wsp:All>  
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>  
</wsp:Policy>
```

Thanks
Alan

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that it could be something to do with the response. I've tried to use wireshark to check the HTTP request, but as it is encrypted and I don't have the private key I can't find a way to confirm what is being sent and recieved from the Java application.

The request from above was captured using TCPMon and going to a local  http port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if the error isn't with the outbound request, but with handling the response.
The response doesn't have a security header and when we're trying to unencrypt it, an exception occurs.

I need to somehow change my Rampart configuration to only do outbound security, not inbound

I'll report back :)

---

Ok the problem was that once Rampart is engaged, it expects the response to have the same security header.
The way I solved the problem was by removing the handler to the Inflow security in the Rampart.mar file.

I'm not sure if this is the best fix, but it worked for us.

To remove the inflow handler:
Unpack the rampart.mar file

Comment out the Inflow section

Zip up the META_INF folder. Then rename the .zip file to be .mar

Now when you use this as there are no handlers defined for inflow, it will just use the standard Axis2 response handler.

I guess if you had several projects using Rampart where some had the security header in the response and some didn't you would need a different approach.

---

Another approach is detailed here.
It's probably a better approach :

http://blog.rampartfaq.com/2009/11/how-to-generate-non-secure-response-to.html

Exception:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
>     at
>   org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:251)    at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)

Answer (score 2):

After navigating a lot, and reading the same pages several times, I finally got a solution that satisfied me.

From previous post I Quote: "Ok the problem was that once Rampart is engaged, it expects the response to have the same security header." (as the request) 
**This is absolutely true!**

I feel that the best approach is found in the following link: http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/11/09/disabling-ws-security-for-in-or-out-messages-in-axis2/

However, in my case, I didn't want to make a new module, so I decided to emulate the module in my code.  I tried to explain it in three steps.

1. (First) I used a default policy (take from the previous link), as a method in my code. (It's worked for Axis 1.6.2 and the compatible version of Rampart)

private String getPolicy()
{
return "xml for policy"
}

**Important** the method must return the following xml as String (better reading)

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="emptryPolicy" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"> 
<wsp:Policy>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

2. (Second) I created a Policy (object) based on the previous method.

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(getPolicy().getBytes());

Policy p = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(stream);

3. (Third) I used the properties of KEY_RAMPART_IN_POLICY and KEY_RAMPART_OUT_POLICY.

Stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_OUT_POLICY,  ***the security policy of the web service***);

Stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_IN_POLICY,  p);

**Important**
The security policy of the web service, depends on the security that the web service uses... If your provider supplied the policy in the wsdl, you would not have to struggle with this... but in other cases, you just use the Rampart Policies. In the rampart site, are examples described very clear for each type of security policy. (UsernameToken Authentication, AsymmetricBinding, etc.)

This example fashions a request with security and response without security.
It Works for me!

Comment: Worked for me, my configuration was applying RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY (another property, without IN or OUT which was applied for both of them). Using an empty policy on the incoming responses with the RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_IN_POLICY is the best solution for this case.

Answer (score -1):

In my case same problem but i got success response by changing the soap request version name space uri in the stub. i have change the name space uri from "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" to "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".

Comment: That *is* the spec the OP is using.